# PHP-tesseract can't get SetImage() to work

Tags: php, ocr, tesseract

I am currently trying to call the `SetImage()` method from the tesseract API via php-tesseract Wrapper class (https://code.google.com/p/php-tesseract/) since I want to use the `setRectangle()` method.

Does somebody know which arguments are expected when using `SetImage()`. I don't know how to pass my image to this method and couldn't find any documentation for PHP on the web.

I am very thankful for any hints or suggestions!

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

From the [sources](https://php-tesseract.googlecode.com/files/tesseract.php):

```
function SetImage($imagedata_or_pix,$width=null,$height=null,$bytes_per_pixel=null,$bytes_per_line=null) {
    switch (func_num_args()) {
        case 1: TessBaseAPI_SetImage($this->_cPtr,$imagedata_or_pix); break;
        case 2: TessBaseAPI_SetImage($this->_cPtr,$imagedata_or_pix,$width); break;
        case 3: TessBaseAPI_SetImage($this->_cPtr,$imagedata_or_pix,$width,$height); break;
        case 4: TessBaseAPI_SetImage($this->_cPtr,$imagedata_or_pix,$width,$height,$bytes_per_pixel); break;
        default: TessBaseAPI_SetImage($this->_cPtr,$imagedata_or_pix,$width,$height,$bytes_per_pixel,$bytes_per_line);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps...